# Python: When attempting to iterate over subprocess output, iteration is by character rather than by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've been trying to teach myself Python 3 with respect to system administration by doing and by researching here on SO.

This function's intent is to call an external command, who -q, and iterate on the output, wrapping each line (user) in HTML tags (save for the final total users line). However, the actual output is each character wrapped in HTML tags.

I can't figure out why it's iterating on each character or how to get it to iterate by line instead.

```
 connusers = str(subprocess.check_output("who -q; exit 0", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode())

 conntable.write("<ul>\n")
 for conn in connusers:
     if "#" not in conn:
         conntable.write("<li>"+ conn +"</li>\n")
 conntable.write("</ul>\n")
```

Comment: `for conn in connusers.splitlines():` ?

Comment: When you iterate over a string, it iterates over each character. That is normal behavior. You can use `.split('\n')` to create a list of lines.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I see now why it was happening like that. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow, you already got two comments explaining how to get it to work, just a quick fyi why this is happening:

A for loop iterates over an iterable, in most cases this is a list and it iterates over the members of that list. In case of strings it iterates over its characters. The lines of your text don't get saved in a list of lines, but in one string with the linebreaks being saved as `\n`. So for python `connusers` is just a long string and it'll iterate over its characters. With the solutions given by **@Rakesh** and **@juanpa.arrivillaga** you split this long string into a list of lines over which you then can iterate.